# building an array from looping an object

Tags: php, arrays, object, laravel, eloquent

I am working on a laravel application at the moment, and I am trying to create an array from an object that is returned from the database by eloquent. The object looks like this,

```
        [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "body": "Fake User created the project Fake Project 2",
        "uri": "8jss90xk",
        "object_id": 422,
        "user": [
          {
            "id": 25,
            "email": "xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com",
            "first_name": "xxx1",
            "last_name": "xxxx1",
            "display_name": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
            "initials": "XX",
            "remember_me": null,
            "active": "1",
            "invite_code": null,
            "forgotten_code": null,
            "cost_visible": 0,
            "login_type": "normal",
            "api_token": null,
            "created_at": "2015-02-13 11:47:24",
            "updated_at": "2015-05-06 22:43:23",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "pivot": {
              "notification_id": 3,
              "user_id": 25,
              "is_read": 0
            }
          }
        ],
        "project": {
          "id": 422,
          "name": "Project Number 1",
          "slug": "Tdc3de97",
          "uri_hash": "project-number-1",
          "description": null,
          "total_cost": "1000.00",
          "start_date": "2015-07-21",
          "finish_date": "2015-10-22",
          "status": 2,
          "sales_person": null,
          "client_id": 0,
          "organisation_id": 97,
          "owner_id": 97,
          "user_id": 25,
          "locked_by": null,
          "created_at": "2015-07-21 13:39:21",
          "updated_at": "2015-07-24 10:07:38",
          "deleted_at": null,
          "archived_at": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
          "invoiced_at": null,
          "is_internal": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "body": "Fake User created the project Fake Project 3",
        "uri": "8jss90xk",
        "object_id": 422,
        "user": [
          {
            "id": 25,
            "email": "XXXXXX@gmail.com",
            "first_name": "XXXXX",
            "last_name": "XXXXXXXX",
            "display_name": "XXX",
            "initials": "XX",
            "remember_me": null,
            "active": "1",
            "invite_code": null,
            "forgotten_code": null,
            "cost_visible": 0,
            "login_type": "normal",
            "api_token": null,
            "created_at": "2015-02-13 11:47:24",
            "updated_at": "2015-05-06 22:43:23",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "pivot": {
              "notification_id": 4,
              "user_id": 25,
              "is_read": 0
            }
          }
        ],
        "project": {
          "id": 422,
          "name": "Project Number 1",
          "slug": "Tdc3de97",
          "uri_hash": "project-number-1",
          "description": null,
          "total_cost": "1000.00",
          "start_date": "2015-07-21",
          "finish_date": "2015-10-22",
          "status": 2,
          "sales_person": null,
          "client_id": 0,
          "organisation_id": 97,
          "owner_id": 97,
          "user_id": 25,
          "locked_by": null,
          "created_at": "2015-07-21 13:39:21",
          "updated_at": "2015-07-24 10:07:38",
          "deleted_at": null,
          "archived_at": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
          "invoiced_at": null,
          "is_internal": 0
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "body": "Fake User created the project Fake Project 4",
        "uri": "8jss90xk",
        "object_id": 422,
        "user": [
          {
            "id": 25,
            "email": "XXXXXXX@gmail.com",
            "first_name": "XXXXXX",
            "last_name": "XXXXXXX",
            "display_name": "XXXXXXX",
            "initials": "XX",
            "remember_me": null,
            "active": "1",
            "invite_code": null,
            "forgotten_code": null,
            "cost_visible": 0,
            "login_type": "normal",
            "api_token": null,
            "created_at": "2015-02-13 11:47:24",
            "updated_at": "2015-05-06 22:43:23",
            "deleted_at": null,
            "pivot": {
              "notification_id": 5,
              "user_id": 25,
              "is_read": 0
            }
          }
        ],
        "project": {
          "id": 422,
          "name": "Project Number 1",
          "slug": "Tdc3de97",
          "uri_hash": "project-number-1",
          "description": null,
          "total_cost": "1000.00",
          "start_date": "2015-07-21",
          "finish_date": "2015-10-22",
          "status": 2,
          "sales_person": null,
          "client_id": 0,
          "organisation_id": 97,
          "owner_id": 97,
          "user_id": 25,
          "locked_by": null,
          "created_at": "2015-07-21 13:39:21",
          "updated_at": "2015-07-24 10:07:38",
          "deleted_at": null,
          "archived_at": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
          "invoiced_at": null,
          "is_internal": 0
        }
      }
}]
```

Basically the query returns all the users with unread notifications, and I want to build that into array along with any notifications and send an email but the array needs to be quite specific with the details it contains.

I imagine sending something like this to mail function that will send the reminders,

```
'user@emailaddress.com' => array(
   'first_name' => 'User',
   'last_name'  => 'Lastname',
   'projects' => array(
       'Project Title 1' => array(
         'notifications' => array(
            [0] => 'Notification 1',
            [1] => 'Notification 2',
            [2] => 'Notification 3'
         )
       )
   )
)
```

I cannot for the live of me work out how to build this array from my object, I currently have this in my code,

```
foreach($unread as $object) {
    $emails_to_send = array(
        'user' => $object->user[0],
        'uri' => $object->uri,
        'body' => $object->body,
        'project' => $object->project
    );
}
```

This however builds the wrong structure and overwrites the last loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wright you have to iterate through your resulting array but like this:

```
// First create the final array
$emails_to_send = array();
foreach($unread as $object) {
    // Add new array element with the email key
    $emails_to_send[$object->user[0]->email] = array(
        'first_name' => $object->user[0]->first_name,
        'last_name' => $object->user[0]->last_name,
        'project' => $object->project
    );
}

var_export($emails_to_send);
```

As a result you will see something like:

```
array(
    'user@emailaddress.com' => array(
        'first_name' => 'User',
        'last_name'  => 'Lastname',
        'project' => array(
            "id" => 422,
            "name" => "Project Number 1",
            "slug" => "Tdc3de97",
            "uri_hash" => "project-number-1",
            ...
        )
    ),
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you get the data overwritten in the last loop is because you assing newly created array to **$emails_to_send** variable instead of appending to the array. Try the following:

```
$emails_to_send = array();

foreach($unread as $object) {
  $emails_to_send[] = array(
    'user' => $object->user[0],
    'uri' => $object->uri,
    'body' => $object->body,
    'project' => $object->project
  );
}

var_dump($emails_to_send);
```

This should give you a list containing one entry for each email that needs to be sent.